# Converting percentage string to a float

Tags: pandas

I have been struggling with converting percentage string to float. I have tried the following code but keep getting value or index errors. Find below the code:

`census_clean.str.replace(r'%', r'.0').astype('float') / 100.0`

can anyone help? how can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

Sample input

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col' : ["100%", "20%"]
})
```

convert

```
df.col.str.replace("%", '').astype(float)
```

result

```
0    100.0
1     20.0
```

Comment: Thank you srinath, i eventually used df.col.astype(str).str.replace('%','').astype(float)/100 and it worked.